# Getting statistics out of table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, statistics

I am very new to programming.

I have the following table, and I need to write a script compatible with ArcMap 10 that will extract some statistics from it. Specifically, I need to obtain a total of all the areas, and then a percentage describing how much of the total area each class of land takes up. If someone knows of a tool or command I should use, that would be a lot of help, even without a script.

```
Id_1    LandClass   F_AREA

    0   Mixed Forest    15612315.78
    0   Softwood Forest 2161121.455
    0   Wetland         2255656.822
    0   Grassy          27009516.24
    0   Hardwood Forest 10345393.4
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that this table is within ArcMap because you calculated the area of each feature in the third column. To extract values from a table that resides in a current ArcMap document, you need to [use cursors](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000). These ArcPython objects loop through each row in a table and allow you read and/or write to that table. If you are only reading information, the loop will be much faster if you use a [SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000); if you want to edit table values, you'll have to use an [UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000).

There are a lot of different ways to go with cursors, but the simplest thing to sum the total area of all features, store it in a variable, then run the division for each feature and store the % of the total in a new field called "Percent_Area" or something like that. I'm assuming you know basic Python.

```
import arcpy

#Below is the name of the table layer in ArcMap.
InputTable = "My Table"

#This searchCursor reads the total area of all features.
TotalArea = 0.0
TableCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(InputTable)
for TableRow in TableCursor:
    TotalArea += TableRow.getValue("F_AREA")
del TableRow
del TableCursor
#At this point 'TotalArea' variable is the sum of all feature areas

#This updateCursor saves the % values for each feature
arcpy.AddField_management(InputTable,"Percent_Area","DOUBLE")
TableCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(InputTable)
for TableRow in TableCursor:
    CurrentArea = TableRow.getValue("F_AREA")
        # area for this feature
    TableRow.setValue("Percent_Area",CurrentArea/TotalArea*100.0)
        # relative area percentage for this feature
    TableCursor.updateRow(TableRow)
del TableRow
del TableCursor
```

For such a small table and such a simple operation it would probably be easiest to just run [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) to get the total area and then do [Field Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000026000000) on a new field to calculate the percentage, but I'm assuming you are using Python for a reason.